# R - Filter 1st Dataframe with conditions of timestamp from DF2

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

DF1:

```
      X        Y        DateTime
1 113.8591 22.25272 2016-01-07 10:37:33
2 113.8585 22.25276 2016-01-07 10:37:43
3 113.8578 22.25270 2016-01-07 10:37:53
4 113.8572 22.25265 2016-02-01 11:34:03
5 113.8565 22.25260 2016-02-18 12:20:13
6 113.8559 22.25251 2016-02-18 12:20:23

structure(list(Date = c("2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", 
"2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", 
"2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", 
"2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", "2016-10-27", 
"2016-10-27", "2016-10-27"), DateTime = structure(c(1477560813, 
1477560823, 1477560833, 1477560843, 1477560853, 1477560863, 1477560873, 
1477560883, 1477560893, 1477560903, 1477560913, 1477560923, 1477560933, 
1477560943, 1477560953, 1477560963, 1477560973, 1477560983, 1477560993, 
1477561003), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Date", "DateTime"))
```

DF2:

```
        DateTimeStart         DateTimeEnd
1 2016-01-07 10:37:00 2016-01-07 10:51:00
2 2016-01-07 10:57:00 2016-01-07 11:14:00
3 2016-01-07 11:36:00 2016-01-07 11:40:00
4 2016-01-07 11:49:00 2016-01-07 12:04:00
5 2016-01-08 12:19:00 2016-01-08 12:35:00
6 2016-02-18 11:51:00 2016-02-18 12:26:00

structure(list(DateTimeStart = structure(c(1477560960, 1477568880, 
1477569780, 1477570500, 1477571460, 1477572240, 1477572720, 1477574700, 
1477575300, 1477575960, 1477579260), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), DateTimeEnd = structure(c(1477561560, 1477569360, 
1477570260, 1477571100, 1477572000, 1477572660, 1477573920, 1477575180, 
1477575840, 1477576680, 1477579920), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("DateTimeStart", 
"DateTimeEnd"))
```

I would like to do filtering for GPS point from DF1 based on whether it falls between the time in each of the DF2 DateTimeStart and DateTimeEnd.
For the above case, I would like to filter out DF1 row 4 since it didn't fall between any of the StartTime & EndTime in DF2.

How to do this with tidyverse/lubridate in R?
Many thanks!

Comment: for(DateTime in DF1$DateTime){
     DF2 %>%
      filter(DateTime > DF2$DateTimeStart & DateTime < DF2$DateTimeEnd)
}

The above code returns the following errors:

50: In <.default`(DateTime, HK_sighting2$DateTimeEnd) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: I can do it like this:

DF2 %>%
  filter(DateTime >= as.POSIXct("2016-10-27 09:36:00") & DateTime <= as.POSIXct("2016-10-27 09:46:00"))


But I dont' know how to write double for-loop

Comment: Could you provide some sample data? Try using `dput()`.

Comment: in the dput code above, It's a bit diff from what I typed in DF1 & DF2. 
In the Dput code, only last few rows in DF2 lies within > 09:36:00 timestamp but it's not functining

Comment: I got this error:

Warning messages:
1: In `>.default`(DateTime, DF2$DateTimeStart) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In `<.default`(DateTime, DF2$DateTimeEnd) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a helper function

```
library(tidyverse)
is_in_interval <- function(x,interval_df){
  (x >= pull(interval_df,1) & x <= pull(interval_df,2)) %>% any()
}
```

and then filter

```
DF1 %>% filter(unlist(map(DateTime, ~ unlist(is_in_interval(.x,DF2)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more convenient

```
DF1 %>% filter(map_lgl(DateTime, ~ unlist(is_in_interval(.x,DF2))))
```

`map` always returns a list, therefore we needed `unlist` to get a vector. `map_lgl` returns a vector of booleans.

Comment: Sorry I have a follow-up question. If I have some associated data in DF2, let's say I have something like how many animals observed in that time period. The unlist function can't relay these data since it returns a booleans. How can I match the associated data? many thanks!

Comment: Or I can simply use a matching function for finding the nearest timestamp I guess

Comment: Update : matching function to the nearest timestamp won't work if the DF2 timestamp are too close to one another