# Compare between 2 dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

DF1:

```
  a  b
1 1  6
2 2  7
3 3  8
4 4  9
5 5 10
```

DF2:

```
  c
1 3
2 8
3 4
4 2
5 9
```

I would like to see if each row of DF2 (column c) is between a & b in DF1;
Hence the resulting filtering will be:

```
  c
1 3
3 4
5 9
```

How should this be done? I have a very long DF2 and a short DF1
I am trying this but get the following error:

```
library(tidyverse)
> c %>%
    filter(c>a & c<b)
```

> Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : Result must have length 5, not 10
>       In addition: Warning message:
>       In c < b : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: Please include the names of any packages you are using in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> library(dplyr)
> df1 <- data.frame (a = c(1,2,3,4,5), b = c(6,7,8,9,10))
> df2 <- data.frame (c = c(3,8,4,2,9))
> 
> df2 %>% filter(c > df1$a & c < df1$b)
  c
1 3
2 4
3 9
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53681333/r-filter-1st-dataframe-with-conditions-of-timestamp-from-df2

This was my original question. It didn't work with timestamp. Can you please help?

Comment: @YuenWaHo could you accept this as an answer then since it does answer the question. I wil take a look on your other question as well.